# How to synchronize a pulse from function generator and an external pulse

Tags: electronics

I am currently trying to sync two pulses. One is from a function generator(5V, 1MHz) and the other is from femtosecond laser(which is 76MHz). The femtosecond laser has a {38MHz, 2V} pulse thats in sync with the 76MHz laser pulse.
The function generator has an ext.trig BNC cable input, and I inserted the 38MHz, 2V pulse. Then I turned on the burst mode.
It seems to synchronize with the laser pulse but it has jitter of 10ns.

I later amplified the 38MHz pulse to 7-8V. But the jitter is still about 10ns.

Is there any way to improve this jitter?
Or is there another way to sync two pulses?

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for the Engineering site than Physics.

Comment: I agree with @PM2Ring

Comment: I disagree that this is engineering - this looks like an acceptable, on-topic question on experimental technique (though it might get a better answer at [electronics.se]). That said, I don't think that this really provides enough information about your setup for anyone to really help diagnose that jitter.

Comment: What is the given spec for triggering the function generator (in the manual)? 10ns jitter on a 1MHz signal generally would be fine. You might need a better function generator, or use a PLL in the trigger path.